# How can I port an Arduino program to .net for use on a Netduino?

Tags: c#, .net, arduino, netduino

I have a program written with the standard Arduino IDE in C.  Is there any way that I can port my program to C# so I can use it with .net and my Netduino?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With enough time, most certainly. You will probably run into problems when your Arduino C/C++ project uses AVR-specific hacks and options like timers and interrupts. From my understanding you can do these more advanced things on the Netduino but there is a significantly different way you'll have to go about coding it.

In order to effectively port the code you'll need a good understanding of C, a strong understanding of C#, as well as the Arduino and Netduino build process, coding conventions, APIs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Netduino has ***absolutely nothing*** to do with an Arduino.

If there isn't a library which understands the Arduino library (like [digitalWrite()]), then you'll need to write those functions in whatever language the Netduino uses.

Answer (score -1):

There's a rough correspondence, but it takes a lot of manual transcoding to port.

Comment: Well sorry... This does not really help :)